# Keyboard shortcut to insert text (soft hyphen) with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I tell CKEditor to insert a soft hyphen (`&shy;`) with a certain keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (hyphen) like in Word? I know I can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0173</kbd>, but my customer doesn't like that.

Comment: Seems like it can be done, see http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.keystrokes for a very rough starting point, but it seems strange that this doesn't already exist.

Comment: Well, thanks, but version 4.5.6 comes without this plugin and simple keystrokes are working anyway. It appears to me that this plugin was for version 3 of CKEditor.

Comment: I have installed it anyway, but couldn't figure out the syntax to add that keystroke.
<code>[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 45 /*-*/, '&shy;' ]</code>

Comment: Get this plugin and modify it to insert your code: http://ckeditor.com/addon/nbsp

Comment: Thanks a bunch.

Sorry for behaving stupid, but how do I get that to work?

I placed plugin.js in /sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/nbsp/
but Ctrl-space doesn't do anything.

Comment: even after adding config.extraPlugins = 'nbsp'; to the config.js

Comment: I finally used builder to put it all together, but the result didn't want to work with Drupal 6 (CKEditor didn't show). Pooh.

Comment: @Pekka웃, you need this for CKEditor4 or CKEditor5? Both are quite different it seems

Comment: @Tarun argh, I just realized the editor my CMS is using is TinyMCE. :( Anyway, let's make this a useful resource - I'd say the latest version is more important but if you can offer an answer for both versions that's great too.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Is it necessary to use keyboard shortcut? I have used other way to insert hyphenation in ckeditor.

Comment: @Lalit in this context I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut (and am pretty happy with Cy's answer), but you're definitely welcome to add your  approach! Going to be useful for future readers finding this, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 15):

### CKEditor 4

We'll use CKEditor's [built-in keybinding API](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.keystrokeHandler) to map a custom command to the custom keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> alone triggers the "zoom out" shortcut in many browsers). We'll wrap this all up [into a plugin](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro) for modularity:

```javascript
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('soft-hyphen-shortcut-key', {
    init: function (editor) {
        var shortcutKeys = CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 189;

        editor.addCommand('insertSoftHyphen', {
            exec: function (editor, data) {
                editor.insertHtml('&shy;');
            }
        });

        editor.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[shortcutKeys] = 'insertSoftHyphen';
    }
});
```

This implementation uses the `insertHtml()` editor method to add the `&shy;` HTML entity to the document at the cursor position when the user presses the key combination. We can initialize a new editor instance with a `<textarea name="editor">` that loads our plugin:

```javascript
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    extraPlugins: 'soft-hyphen-shortcut-key'
});
```

Here's a [demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrossignol/3e2jqkyk/5/) (I had to make this external—code snippets won't work with CKEditor's `<iframe>`).

### CKEditor 5

This version is in *alpha* at the time of writing, so the API and documentation may not be complete. Version 5 dramatically changes the architecture of the project, including a switch to ES6 for the source code, so I won't demonstrate how to create a plugin for this version (we'd need to build it). Instead, we'll create the same functionality as we would with the plugin when we initialize the editor:

```javascript
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor1'))
    .then(function (editor) {
        var shortcutKeys = [ 'Ctrl', 'Shift', 189 ];
        var softHyphen = '\u00AD';

        editor.keystrokes.set(shortcutKeys, function () {
            editor.execute('input', { text: softHyphen });
        });
    });
```

Version 5 doesn't seem to include an equivalent to `insertHtml()` from version 4 yet, so the example uses the Unicode character for the soft hyphen. Here's the [demo for v5](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrossignol/x5LhLzbd/5/).

For those interested in creating a custom plugin and command for version 5, see the documentation for the [CKEditor 5 Framework](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html). This requires an environment where we can install the framework's npm packages. We'll use ES6 to extend the framework's classes and Webpack to bundle them up.

---

A quick note to address the bounty: we can [bind key combinations similarly](https://go.tinymce.com/blog/creating-keyboard-shortcuts-tinymce/) in TinyMCE ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrossignol/e5c3wbbr/)):

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.shortcuts.add("ctrl+shift+189", 'Insert Soft Hyphen', function () {
            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '\u00AD');
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Ctrl` + `-`, you can use `Alt` + `-`. Because `Ctrl` + `-` browser's default allocated key which uses to zoom out.

Here is an sort example :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.shortcuts.add("alt+189", 'Insert Soft Hyphen', function () {
            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&shy;');
        })
    }
});
```